# MySQL: Get dates with and without category/subcategory in ONE query (and sorted)

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database with 4 tables with this structure:

- categories
- subcategories
- dates
- events

We have events, that can have multiple dates. Events are categorized in categories and subcategories, but can have only a category and no subcategory, too.

I  tried this query:

```
SELECT
    t.id as sortid,
    t.numprint,
    s.titel,
    s.intro,
    s.inhalte,
    s.zielgruppe,
    s.methoden,
    s.kapitelprint,
    s.unterkapitelprint,
    t.ort,
    t.bundesland,
    t.email,
    t.telefon,
    t.preis,
    t.dateprint
FROM
    kapitel k
LEFT JOIN
    unterkapitel u
    ON u.parent = k.id
LEFT JOIN
    seminare s
    ON s.kapitel = k.id
    AND s.unterkapitel = u.id
    AND s.aktiv = 1
LEFT JOIN
    termine t
    ON t.parent = s.id
```

But this doesn't get the events with no subcategory - they all have NONE in all fields.
Is there a way to get all dates in one query?

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

Comment: Please provide your database scheme. Also, your select requests a t and s, but those are never defined in a from or join clause.

Comment: Hi Josh, sorry, I've updated my query. My original query contains german fieldnames that some might not understand - so I translated the query into English. I've now posted my original query - hopefully that most will understand what I'm doing anyway.

Comment: Hehe, you translated 'a', 't' & 's' from German to English?  (Not that it is bad form to define an alias as a reasonable first character of a table, it's not necessary & works just as fine with a random alias)

Comment: hehe, well my original fields had german names, like "seminar", which is german for "event" (in a wide definition). so i changed it to e and event instead of s and seminar. but this is to confusing, so i posted my original query.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if seminar (English) was almost the same meaning as seminar (German) :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, last shot:

if you want *all* kapitels, regardless of whether they have an event.

```
SELECT * 
FROM kapitel k

LEFT JOIN seminare s
ON s.kapitel = k.id
    AND s.aktiv = 1

LEFT JOIN termine t
ON t.parent = s.id

LEFT JOIN unterkapitel u
ON u.parent = k.id
    AND s.unterkapitel = u.id
```

If you want *only* events / siminare:

```
SELECT * 
FROM seminare s

JOIN kapitel k
ON s.kapitel = k.id
    AND s.aktiv = 1

LEFT JOIN termine t
    ON t.parent = s.id

LEFT JOIN unterkapitel u
ON u.parent = k.id
    AND s.unterkapitel = u.id
```

But I don't really like it that in theory is is possible a Seminar can have a Kapital & Unterkapitel which aren't related (which you can prevent in script of course), I keep thinking there should be a better layout for this, but the only thing I can think of is merging Kapitel & Unterkapitel into 1 table with a simple Adjancency Model, keeping you free to enter either an Kapitel or Unterkapitel in a single 'kapitel' field in Seminare, dropping the Unterkapitel field entirely.

Comment: Well this does not work as expected. Rows should be 356, now it's 374.

    SELECT
  t.id as sortid,
  t.numprint,
  s.titel,
  s.intro,
  s.inhalte,
  s.zielgruppe,
  s.methoden,
  s.kapitelprint,
  s.unterkapitelprint,
  t.ort,
  t.bundesland,
  t.email,
  t.telefon,
  t.preis,
  t.dateprint
 FROM
  kapitel k
 LEFT JOIN
  unterkapitel u
  ON u.parent = k.id
 LEFT JOIN
  seminare s
  ON s.kapitel = k.id
  AND ( s.unterkapitel = u.id OR s.unterkapitel IS NULL)
  AND s.aktiv = 1
 LEFT JOIN
  termine t
  ON t.parent = s.id

Comment: Damn, I feel like a newbie posting here ;)

Comment: Does the latter one work (is somewhat more robust): `s.unterkapitel <=> u.id` (assuming the value in `s.unterkapitel` is NULL when not defined)

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to think about it. The problem is not actually getting a join to the subkapitel, but actually trying to NOT getting a join to it...

Answer (score 0):

Wrikken, thanks! But this doesn't return the correct order.

I need all events (termine) from all kapitel (categories), including their unterkapitel (subcategories), but in their correct order:

- sample date 1 with category a
- sample date 2 with category b, subcategory b.a
- sample date 3 with category b, subcategory b.a
- sample date 4 with category b, subcategory b.b
- sample date 6 with category b, subcategory b.c
- sample date 7 with category c, subcagetory c.a

... and so on.

ie.: go into the categories, return any dates without subcategory or go into the subcategories, loop trough all of them and return all dates from these subcategories.

at the moment I'm doing this logic inside my python script, but I thought this should be possible with MySQL directly.

Comment: I'm not really clear on this (and I'd advise it to add this to your question in an edit rather then as an answer). There was no order clause yet, but from your example I'd say that a simple `ORDER BY k.id,  u.id IS NULL, u.id` should do the trick? Or should there be sorted by termine first?